# How to Join three semi related tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have three tables in a Mysql database - countries, cities and hotels. Their relations are: countries hasMany cities and cities hasMany hotels.

I want to be able to select all hotels given a certain countries.id. I am pretty weak in SQL. The join statement i came up with is as follows which always returns 0 rows.

```
SELECT 
    countries.name as country,
    cities.name as city,
    hotels.name as hotel
FROM 
    countries
    left join cities
        on countries.id = cities.country_id
    left join hotels
        on cities.id = hotels.city_id

WHERE
    countries.id = @id
```

help?

Comment: Are you setting the value of @id? Try replacing @id with an actual value, such as 1. "countries.id = 1", depending on what your actual country ids are

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the statement. Does your countries table actually contains any data? What do you pass in `@id`? What does `select * from countries` return?

Comment: *face palm* the country id i was using didnt have any matching records. i cant award a comment the right answer can i? xP

Comment: @Shafee - Bryan posted the suggestion first. You can ask him to write it up as answer and accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try leaving *off* the where clause and see what records you *actually* have. Maybe the specific id you're using is not a known country id.

---

Also, just on a strictly formatting/style issue, IMHO this is better:

```
SELECT 
    countries.name as country,
    cities.name as city,
    hotels.name as hotel
FROM countries
left join cities on cities.country_id = countries.id
left join hotels on hotels.city_id = cities.id
WHERE countries.id = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb is to always start my FROM clause with the table of the actual thing I want as my results.

```
SELECT 
  countries.name as country,
  cities.name as city,
  hotels.name as hotel
FROM  
  hotels JOIN cities ON cities.id = hotels.city_id
  join countries on countries.id = cities.country_id
WHERE
  countries.id = @id
```

added benefit is that you don't need outer joins :-)